# Abstract class with static methods. Is that correct?

Tags: java, android

**Task**: I want to use some methods for many classes. Methods are same, so there is no need to implement them for each class. In my case - I work with android SDK and I send http request to server.

**Problem**: There is idea to use construction like this:

```
class abstract MethodsCarrier{

    public static void method1(){ /*something*/ }
    public static int method2(){ /*return something*/ }

}
```

It works, there is no problems. But I'm not sure about making this class abstract. Is it's a right way at all?

Comment: CodeInChaos's suggestion is a good one. Abstract classes are normally used as base classes that expect to be subclassed, like `AbstractList`, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd prefer a `final` class with no public constructors. That's the way sun did it with the `Math` class, so I assume that's the conventional way to do this in java.

---

But in your case, I'd avoid static. Static methods are good for side effect free functions that don't access any external(or global mutable) state. A http request does access external state.

I'd define an interface with this methods, write one implementation that does the requests, and then use an IoC container to inject it into the consuming code in a singleton context. That way you can mock the interface, so you don't need to make http requests while testing.

Comment: +1. And I'd also prefer methods which conform to the Java naming conventions and thus start with a lower-case letter.

Comment: CodeInChaos, can you provide a short example of using singleton in this case? I found some solutions, but not sure which one (and how) to use.

Comment: @biovamp I can't provide an example in java since I don't use java. Choose a inversion-of-control framework, and check its documentation. The important point is to use a IoC singleton and not a `Class.GetInstance()` singleton.

Comment: Thanks, you just save me from .getInstance() :)